# How to draw braces over segment in metapost?

Tags: metapost

I want to draw brace over straight line it Metapost. In LaTeX, I can draw
brace like following:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}
 \overbrace{text}
 \end{document}
```

Is it something standard out there, or my wish is unusual and I should create picture with

```
btex \{ etex
```

and rotate/shift/scale it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [cmarrows](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/cmarrows/cmarrows.pdf) package from Tommy Ekola. An example from its documentation:

```
input cmarrows;
    setup_cmarrows(
      brace_name     = "bigbrace";
      parameter_file = "cmr10.mf";
      macro_name     = "bracea");
    setup_cmarrows(
      brace_name     = "Biggbrace";
      parameter_file = "cmr12.mf";
      macro_name     = "braceb");
    setup_cmarrows(
      brace_name     = "extensiblebrace";
      parameter_file = "cmr9.mf";
      macro_name     = "bracec");
    beginfig(1);
      bracea (0,0)--70pt*dir 0;
      braceb_middle_time:=0.7;
      braceb (0,0)--70pt*dir 60
        withcolor 0.5*white;
      bracec_middle_time:=0.3;
      bracec (0,0)..{up}70pt*dir 120;
endfig; end
```

[image]